# ListView Image Selection Mask

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I have a ListView in `View = LargeIcons`. I added an icon which I have done as PNG (black with white background, 32bit ARGB) and two icons I have done with `System.Drawing.Graphics` (white background, Pixelformat 32bppArgb).

When I selected the icons in the list, the PNG is masked/highlighted fine, but my custom icons drawn programatically have awful artefacts when masked/highlighted (last two ones in the screenshot).

Have a look:
[image]

How can I render my icons as fine as the external graphic?

---

Generation code:

```
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(THUMB_WIDTH, THUMB_HEIGHT, formatThumbs);
    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
        g.Clear(Color.White);                
        g.DrawEllipse(penThumbLine, 1, 1, THUMB_WIDTH - 2, THUMB_HEIGHT - 2);
    }
    return bmp;
```

When I change the `Clear` color to `Color.Transparent` there is no highlight visible when the entry/icon is selected. The `ImageList` `TransparentColor` is `Color.Transparent`.

Comment: The anti-aliasing pixels that make the black shape blend nicely onto the white background become readily visible when the background is no longer white.  Can't otherwise troubleshoot code from a screenshot.

Comment: I added the generation code. I know that the anti-alias pixels are not completly white but should the selection-overlay just color everything to a certain target and not only white pixels?

Comment: Your graphic might have gotten resampled when it was added to the image list, further messing up the anti-aliasing.  What is THUMB_WIDTH/HEIGHT and what is the ImageList.ImageSize and ColorDepth?

Comment: `THUMB_WIDTH` = 240, `THUMB_HEIGHT` = 140, `ImageList.ImageSize` = 240;140, `ColorDepth` = `Depth32bit`

Comment: I can repro now.  Your ImageList.TransparentColor probably isn't Color.White.  Making them match however produces a very different selection mask, colorizing the curve instead of the background.  No idea how to get the png selection mode.  Consider using SmoothingMode.None.